# Constructing Logic

Tags: c#, logic

Hello I was practicing some coding (hacker rank challenges) but I am failing on constructing a basic logic and I feel as if I'm over looking something incredibly simple.
The intent of my program is that given an array of 6 x 6 as Input I calculate each hourglass sum and display only the max sum.
The input into the array ranges from -9 to 9 inclusive. 
So if my input array is

7 8 9 1 2 3

5 6 7 3 4 2

7 9 5 1 3 5

7 9 5 2 1 1

9 5 3 1 3 3

7 6 1 3 5 8

It should display the max sum from all the calculated hourglasses. An example of hourglass would be

7 8 9

...6

7 9 5

Which also happens to be the highest sum (51) in this particular array.
The problem I'm facing is displaying the max sum when all my input are negative numbers.

-1 -1 0 -9 -2 -2

-2 -1 -6 -8 -2 -5

-1 -1 -1 -2 -3 -4

-1 -9 -2 -4 -4 -5

-7 -3 -3 -2 -9 -9

-1 -3 -1 -2 -4 -5

That is the array I'm failing a test case for. So in my code when I declare my variable current sum and max sum, I initialize them both to zero. After calculating each sum I check whether or not my current sum is greater than my max sum, however, in the case of all negative integers when my current sum is already less than the max sum it'll never go into that if statement and I'm failing to see what counter part condition should I put to cater in case my current sum is already less than zero.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;

namespace C_hash_Tutorials
{
    class HackerRank_Day11
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] arr = new int[6][];
            string[] arr_temp;
            int arr_i = 0;
            int curr_sum = 0;
            int max_sum = 0;
            for (arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++)
            {
                arr_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                arr[arr_i] = Array.ConvertAll(arr_temp, Int32.Parse);
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < arr.Length-2; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < arr.Length-2; y++)
                {
                    curr_sum = arr[x][y] + arr[x][y + 1] + arr[x][y + 2] + arr[x + 1][y + 1] + arr[x + 2][y] + arr[x + 2][y + 1] + arr[x + 2][y + 2];
                    Console.WriteLine(curr_sum);
                    if (curr_sum > max_sum)
                    {
                        max_sum = curr_sum;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(max_sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The lowest possible value is the sum of seven -9's, so initialize your variables to -64 and it should work.

Comment: Aye that would work. Thanks. Before I initialized my max sum to -100 as a safety precaution but while doing that I felt as if I was cheating on the logic of the condition statements. Thanks. This makes more logical sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all you have to do is to initialize   `max_sum` as minimum:

```
int curr_sum = 0;
int max_sum = int.MinValue;
...
```

Comment: Yeah I could do that and that would work perfectly fine. I initialized it to -100 before but I felt as if I was cheating on the logic when calculating the sums so I took to you guys to see if I was over looking something incredibly simple while constructing the condition statements.

Answer (score 1):

When solving such problems (summing some kind of *hour glasses*) the very first intent is to *generate* these hour glasses as a *separated routine*:

```
private static IEnumerable<T[]> HourGlasses<T>(T[][] source) {
  if (null == source)
    yield break;

  for (int r = 0; r < source.Length - 2; ++r) {
    T[] top = source[r];
    T[] middle = source[r + 1];
    T[] bottom = source[r + 2];

    int n = Math.Min(Math.Min(top.Length - 2, bottom.Length - 2), middle.Length - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      yield return new T[] {
        top[i],    top[i + 1],    top[i + 2],
                   middle[i + 1],
        bottom[i], bottom[i + 1], bottom[i + 2], };
  }
}
```

Having this *method extracted*, you can easily answer your question:

```
int[][] arr = ...

...
int max = HourGlasses(arr)               // extract each hour glass
  .Select(hourGlass => hourGlass.Sum())  // sum up items within each hour glass
  .Max();                                // return the max of these sums
```

Please notice, that now you can easily find out the *Min*, *ArgMax* (which hour glass has the maximum sum) etc.

Comment: I'll look over this and play with the code so I understand it better. Thank you for another, detailed, answer.